# Can reader tags be used with ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In Clojure, adding custom reader tags is really simple

```
;; data_readers.clj (on classpath, eg. src/clj/)
{rd/qux datareaders.reader/my-reader}

;; Define a namespace containing the my-reader var:
(ns datareaders.reader)
(defn my-reader [x] 'y)

;; use special tag in other namespace. Readers have to be required first.

(require 'datareaders.reader)
(defn foo [x y] 
  (println #rd/qux x "prints y, not x due to reader tag."))
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing for ClojureScript but am getting an error that `#rd/qux` is not defined. I am using `lein cljsbuild once` to build the project. Is that a limitation of ClojureScript or is it that `cljsbuild` builds the project before the readers have been resolved? In that case, how can I force leiningen to load the readers namespace before cljsbuild is started?

EDIT: Note that this example intends to use reader tags within ClojureScript source code and not when reading auxilliary data via `read-string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>This currently isn't possible, but will be as soon as [#CLJS-1194](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1194) and [#CLJS-1277](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1277) are fixed. Hopefully that will happen very soon.</s>

If you wanted to do it, just rename `data_readers.clj` to `data_readers.cljc` and use conditional readers.

As an aside, what's your use case for this?

Both [#CLJS-1194](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1194) and [#CLJS-1277](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1277) are fixed, so this should work as expected.

Comment: I intended to write a macro that will process the tags in a particular way. Essentially to remove some boilerplate I have when developing with ClojureScript/reagent. I tried to model some components via edn and was successful to use custom tags to make it more readable. Since some components come via edn, other components via source code, I thought it might be useful to use the same syntax in both places. However, it's not a problem to just use a plain macro, it's just less symmetric then.

Comment: A practical example for me is i18n:
;; with re-frame I need to write this.
`(defn component []
  (let [text (subscribe [:i18n :key])]
    (fn [] [:div {} @text])))`

;; But I want to write this
`(x/defn component []
  [:div {} #i18n :key])`


the vector `[:div {} #:i18n :key]` can be stored somewhere as plain data and also be used in a rendering function.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism to add a custom reader tag in cljs is different. You have to call `register-tag-parser!` which takes a tag and a fn.

From the [cljs reader tests](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/cfdb0d4fb6993f121712040671188523f8c8b20f/src/test/cljs/cljs/reader_test.cljs#L85):

```
(testing "Testing tag parsers"
    (reader/register-tag-parser! 'foo identity)
    (is (= [1 2] (reader/read-string "#foo [1 2]")))
```

Your example would be:

```
(cljs.reader/register-tag-parser! 'rd/qux (fn [x] 'y))
(defn foo [x y] 
  (println #rd/qux x "prints y, not x due to reader tag."))
```

Comment: I think that `register-tag-parser` is used in conjunction with `read-string`. When source code is processed this seems to have no effect, I still get the same error.

Comment: Hummm you are right, `register-tag-parser!` is not for the compiler.